# Заполнить массив случайными числами без повторов

Tags: javascript, массивы, случайные-числа

Я ощущаю разращение безумия. Требуется получить уникальный массив N длины из случайных чисел.

```js
var arr = [],
    a = ~~(Math.random() * 42),
    i = 0;
while(b !== 42) {
    for(i=0; i<42; i+=1) {
        if(arr[i] !== a) {
            arr.push(a);
            a = ~~(Math.random() * 42);
            b+=1;
        }else{
            a = ~~(Math.random() * 42);
        }
    }
}
```

В итоге массив arr заполняется местами одинаковыми числами. Прошу помощи сообщества, в т.ч. показать Ваши лучшие реализации, кои Вы таковыми можете считать, при желании.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Math.random` возвращает *независимые* случайные числа, соответственно, для получения случайной последовательности *уникальных* (то есть со всех сторон зависимых) чисел использовать ваш способ будет крайне нерационально.

Чтобы получить нужный вам список, следует заполнить массив последовательными числами в нужном вам диапазоне, а потом перемешать (отсортировать в случайном порядке).

Вот кнутовская реализация перемешивания:

```
function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex ;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}
```

Ну а дальше:

```
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 42; i++)
  arr.push(i);
shuffle(arr);
console.log(arr);
```

См. [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976)

Comment: Получившийся массив не будет содержать случайных чисел, а лишь конкретные числа в случайном порядке. Ваш алгоритм со стопроцентной вероятностью сгенерирует массив из числе о A до B

Comment: @P.Ilyin Спасибо, К.О.

Comment: если это так очевидно, зачем предлагать заведомо неверный алгоритм?

Comment: @P.Ilyin Потому что это то, что нужно автору вопроса.

Answer (score 3):

Вы заполняете массив из N элементов N разными числами в диапазоне от 0 до N?

Но результат такого заполнения называется перестановкой, таким образом вам надо сгенерировать случайную перестановку. Вот третья ссылка по этому запросу в гугле:

[Метод генерации случайной перестановки, алгоритм Фишера-Йетса](http://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8,_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%99%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%B0)

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr = []                         //записываем в этот массив рандомные числа
var max;                              // максимальная длина массива 
var rundomnumber;                     //случайное число

while (arr.length <= max) {

    rundomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * max); //создадим случайное число

    if (arr.indexOf(rundomnumber) == -1) {         // проверим есть оно  у нас или нет 

        arr.push(rundomnumber);         // записываем в массив т.к нету

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто включать каждое новое число проверив на повторение в массиве

```js
var arr, max_number, i, unic;
arr = [];
max_number = 42;
while (arr.length < 42) {
  do {
    unic = true;
    a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 42);
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (a == arr[i]) {
        // такое число уже было
        unic = false;
        break;
      }
    }
  } while (!unic) // повторить генерацию числа
  arr.push(a);
}
console.log(arr.join(";"))​;
```

Comment: Лучше просто сдвигать.

Answer (score 0):

```
var size =  25, arr = [], pool = [];

for(var i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
    arr.push(i);
}

for(var i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
   var value =  arr.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * ((size-i) - 1) + 1),1);
   pool.push(value.pop());
}
return pool;
```

Массив - pool на выходе состоит из size случайных , не повторяющихся значений